# virtualbox - ubuntu server website not working

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2

I am running VirtualBox with Ubuntu Server 16.04 and Windows 10 as a host. However after setting everything up, database tables, webmin works absolutely fine, in Apache I have set up a path to my laravel which is `/var/www/fyproject/public` but when I put IP address into a browser I get:

```
192.168.1.105 The server refused the connection.
```

I can ping my Ubuntu server from Windows and it works fine so why that doesn't?

Output from sudo netstat:

tcp 6 0    0 :::80     :::*    LISTEN 1357/apache2

Comment: Are you trying to access the `laravel app` from Windows ?

Comment: Does httpd listen on port 80 on all interfaces? In ubuntu, try `sudo netstat -nap | grep apache` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Yes @George that's exactly what I want to do, I will do that now

Comment: Change the virtualbox network adapter to either `bridged` or `host-only` see which works

Comment: @ridgy Done it, see the question

Comment: apache is listening on TCP6 port 80. I don't know if the virtualbox network supports/routes V6. You may edit `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` to read `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` to use IPV4 (see e.g. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html)

Comment: So i have added Listen 0.0.0.0:80 inside <ifmodule> but when i to netstat i still get tcp6 only

Comment: [link](http://guntars.github.io/tech/2014/12/06/guide_to_installing_ubuntu_server_with_apache_mysql_php_laravel/) I have followed this guide to set it up and there is nothing about this problem there and no setting up either

Comment: I did not mean 'add ... inside <IfModule>' - sorry to not be exact. You should change `Listen 80` to  `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`. And do not forget to tell apache to reload the configuration! Usually you do not need that in real life - IPV4 will be mapped to some IPV6, but I am not sure if this the case with virtualbox in Windows

Comment: Okay, maybe a bit off topic but if I have this virtualbox set up, how would i make it work outside network? so for example I would be able to access it from another laptop?

Comment: You might ask this question in another community. I don't use Windows, and I don't use Virtualbox - but a lot of other people could help with trhat.

Comment: Where could I ask about it?>

Comment: I think the problem is the files permission there are certain files that need to have write permission in laravel and if they are not enabled then you can't open the laravel app...did you fix the problem?